# Hi how to show message in table format in Chtbot

Tags: python, html, excel, rasa

Hi i am fetching data from the Excel sheet which contains multiple columns and rows. Is there any way to show data of the message in a tabular format, currently I am using the RASA framework for bot integration. I want to show a table on the bot.
What other option to show data of the message in a tabular format

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the capabilities of the chat widget you choose. Rasa will pass on whatever text content you supply as the response. For example, the Botfront Rasa chat widget has a [list](https://github.com/botfront/rasa-webchat) of the supported content types.

For tables, you might try a Markdown table (not sure if Botfront's markdown supports that) or you could generate an image with the table.